# Javascript output not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, output

We have a JavaScript assignment that we have to do. We have to build a sentence generator. When I run this in Chrome, nothing happens when I click the buttons. When I check the Console Log, it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: mySubject is not defined.` I thought I defined it already in `element1.onclick` function?

This is my code so far:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="btn1">Generate subject</button>
            <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject"
            />
            <button id="btn2">Generate verb</button>
            <input name="verb" type="text" id="verb" />
            <button id="btn3">Generate adjective</button>
            <input name="adj" type="text" id="adj" />
            <button id="btn4">Generate object</button>
            <input name="object" type="text" id="object" />
        </div>
        <!--buttons closing div-->
        <div>
            <p id="output">asjkldhfahfjasf;d</p>
        </div>
        <!--output closing div-->
    </div>
    <!--container closing div-->
    <script>
        var subject = new Array("Mel Gibson", "Optimus-Prime", "The Cat-lady", "The student", "My Dentist");

        var verb = new Array("licks", "pets", "hugs", "stabs", "eats");

        var adj = new Array("fat", "ugly", "delicious", "redundant", "hopeless");

        var object = new Array("cat", "bacon-strip", "dog-house", "bigmac", "hobo");


        var element1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
        var element2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
        var element3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
        var element4 = document.getElementById("btn4");

        element1.onclick = function() {
            mySubject = subject[Math.random() * subject.length]
        };

        element2.onclick = function() {
            myVerb = verb[Math.random() * verb.length]
        };

        element3.onclick = function() {
            myAdj = adj[Math.random() * adj.length]
        };

        element4.onclick = function() {
            myObject = object[Math.random() * object.length]
        };

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mySubject + myVerb + " the" + myAdj + myObject + ".";
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm starting to get so lost and have no idea what to do and this is only one of the many problems I have.

**EDIT:**

So I got some help with my Javascript and everything is now working except for the output. I want it to output into the output div, but it's not outputting anything. This is my code now:

```
<h1>The Amazing Fantastical Sentence Generator!</h1>

<h4>Have hours of fun with your imaginary friends!</h4>
</div><!--title closing div-->
<div id="buttons">

<button id="btn1">Generate subject</button>
<input name="subject" type="text" id="insubject"/>



<button id="btn2">Generate verb</button>
<input name="verb" type="text" id="verb"/>

<button id="btn3">Generate adjective</button>
<input name="adj" type="text" id="adj"/>


<button id="btn4">Generate object</button>
<input name="object" type="text" id="object"/>
```

```
<div >
<p id="output"></p>
</div><!--output closing div-->

</div><!--container closing div-->

<script>


var subject=new Array("Mel Gibson", "Optimus-Prime", "The Cat-lady", "The student", "My        Dentist");

var verb=new Array("licks", "pets", "hugs", "stabs", "eats");

var adj=new Array("fat", "ugly", "delicious", "redundant", "hopeless");

var object=new Array("cat", "bacon-strip", "dog-house", "bigmac", "hobo");


var element1=document.getElementById("btn1");
var element2=document.getElementById("btn2");
var element3=document.getElementById("btn3");
var element4=document.getElementById("btn4");

element1.onclick=function()  {document.getElementById('insubject').value=subject[Math.floor(Math.random()*(subject.length))];}

element2.onclick=function(){document.getElementById('verb').value=verb[Math.floor(Math.random()*(verb.length))];}

element3.onclick=function(){document.getElementById('adj').value=adj[Math.floor(Math.random()*(adj.length))];}

element4.onclick=function(){document.getElementById('object').value=object[Math.floor(Math.random()*(object.length))];}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= document.getElementById("insubject").value + document.getElementById("verb").value + " the" + document.getElementById("adj").value + document.getElementById("object").value + ".";


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to fix this.

After having edited my code again, all the buttons were working, but they were not outputting correctly into the output div. So I declared all the Math.Random equations that were being run on my arrays, so that they all had a default answer. Also I created a default output that would display in the output div.

```
var subStr = subject[Math.floor(Math.random()*(subject.length))];
var verbStr = verb[Math.floor(Math.random()*(verb.length))];
var adjStr = adj[Math.floor(Math.random()*(adj.length))];
var objStr = object[Math.floor(Math.random()*(object.length))];

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= subStr + " " + verbStr + " the " + adjStr + " " + objStr + " .";
```

Then I changed my onclick events.

```
element1.onclick=function(){

subStr = subject[Math.floor(Math.random()*(subject.length))];
document.getElementById('insubject').value=subStr;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= subStr + " " + verbStr + " the " + adjStr + " " + objStr + " .";

}

element2.onclick=function(){

verbStr = verb[Math.floor(Math.random()*(verb.length))];
document.getElementById('verb').value=verbStr;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= subStr + " " + verbStr + " the " + adjStr + " " + objStr + " .";
}


 element3.onclick=function(){

adjStr= adj[Math.floor(Math.random()*(adj.length))];
document.getElementById('adj').value=adjStr;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= subStr + " " + verbStr + " the " + adjStr + " " + objStr + " .";
}

element4.onclick=function(){

objStr= object[Math.floor(Math.random()*(object.length))];
document.getElementById('object').value=objStr;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= subStr + " " + verbStr + " the " + adjStr + " " + objStr + " .";
}
```

Now each Math.random was being calculated again, followed by it being inputted into the specific text field, and then outputting into the output div.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside functions are **local** to those functions, which means that you can't use them outside of those functions. Try declaring your variables as global outside of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

> When I check the Console Log, it says Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   mySubject is not defined. I thought I defined it already in
>   element1.onclick function?

JavaScript scope is [**function scope**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). Any variable declared within a function only can be accessed by that function and any nested functions but not the outer ones.

If you want to access `mySubject` outside the function too you need to declare it where you have `verb, subject, etc..` delcared.

In addition, even though you still have the issue that your `document.getElementById` command is using `mySubject` before the click event is assigning it but that is a different issue I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

you should define the mySubject variable along with myVerb and myAdj as follows :

```
var mySubject;
var myVerb;
var myAdj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining it inside a `function`. Declare them outside the function, then try assigning them the value inside.